# I disabled root access on my server, but now I cant FTP files to /var/www/, any solutions?

Tags: server, root, ftp

Following a tutorial for Linode to host a server securely, I disabled root user.

I have regular user, and I can always type in sudo if I want to make changes. The problem exists when I try to FTP stuff into these folders that I would need to type in sudo.

Any ideas how I can directly upload to these folders? If not, whats my best option? Upload to my user folder and copy everything?

Answer (score 0):

I am still a newbie so this may not be correct.

You mentioned that you wanted to host your server securely and want to FTP stuff. Now I was under the impression that FTP was not the most secure way to transfer files. Maybe I am wrong.

I wonder if scp would achieve what you want? 
Sorry to post a link but there is a lot of information here that could be useful.

[**In Unix, how do I use SCP to securely transfer files between two computers?**
 - In Unix, you can use SCP (the scp command) to securely copy files and directories between remote hosts without starting an FTP session or logging into the remote systems explicitly. The scp command uses SSH to transfer data, so it requires a password or passphrase for authentication. Unlike rcp or FTP, scp encrypts both the file and any passwords exchanged so that anyone snooping on the network cannot view them.](https://kb.iu.edu/d/agye)

Answer (score 0):

Well, if your ftp user does not have write permission for the folder he is supposed to, he won't be able to. Either give that user write permissions to the specific folder, or ftp the files to a directory where he has write right, and then log in via ssh and move the files around.

`scp` is also a more secure and as convenient way to copy some files to a server with ssh running.